# gnuplot - can't get a histogram - always plots a normal function

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I want to plot a simple histogram, using raw data. ie, I have a file with a single column (for testing I just put there 1000 normal random variables so that I would get a nice gaussian like histogram).

I write:

```
reset
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster
plot newhistogram "A", "mydata"
```

But all I get is just the function itself (IE instead of the x axis being the bins, it's just a number from 0 to 1000, just like I plotted the data file itself).
How can I create a proper histogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Theory

To plot a histogram your data needs to be setup like this:

```
<cluster name 1> <data 11> <data 12> ... <data 1n>
<cluster name 2> <data 21> <data 22> ... <data 2n>
...
<cluster name m> <data m1> <data m2> ... <data mn>
```

Then you can set the style of your histogram with for example:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster
set style fill solid 1.0   #<this only makes the histogram bars filled with a color
```

With a data file `Data.csv` and `n = 6` you can iterate over all values with

```
plot for [i = 2 : 6] "Data.csv" u i:xticlabel(1)
```

### Example

#### Data.csv

```
col1 0.7585169 0.9014084 0.0530081 0.5387650 0.3958664 0.7884399
col2 0.5492615 0.1042125 0.4758576 0.2488184 0.0039956 0.3210850
col3 0.4668526 0.6453222 0.1703792 0.0229689 0.7916639 0.6115277
```

#### Gnuplot Script

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster
set style fill solid 1.0

plot for [i = 2 : 6] "Data.csv" u i:xticlabel(1)
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks. So you mean I can't really use gnuplot to produce me a histogram from raw data? I have to manipulate it first? Because I did use the method with "hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width" and it does produce a histogram, but I now need to produce one near the other...

Comment: @ido Sorry I cannot follow your question. What do you mean by "raw data"? What do you mean with "produce one near the other..."?

Comment: Hi. I mean that I take a list of values (for example data I got from a measurement of some sort) and want to produce a histogram (similar to matlab's hist() function for example). I also want to be able to put several data sources in the same plot (similar to the image above).

Comment: @ido What do you get when you follow my example above?